# PHP to Word Template

Tags: php, .doc

Hi I would be grateful for someones help in this, and i am sure it has probably been asked before.

I currently have a MySQL database that is accessed by my own PHP front end.  I can already output to a basic word document, but what i need very specifically is the following:

I would like to take an existing word document that is setup as a company template, note here that the key is i am not wanting to export data into a blank document.

What options / how can i set this up so that the application sends data into a word (XML or similar) and then get word to put the data in the right place like a mail merge?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Update: To be specific, I al looking at making an inspection report, so am not looking to merge 100's of records from a table, I am wanting to do an inspection on a construction site, then use a method to get the current record, and export it into a template word document

Comment: https://phpword.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: Have you considered actually using Mail Merge?  You can write a SQL statement right there, assuming you have access to the server.

Comment: I can access the server no problem, but would have no idea at all how to do this

Comment: You are able to do this using pure PHP.
At http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee840137%28v=office.12%29.aspx you will find a maner to personalize Word templates and save it as a different file.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a class in PHP for Laravel 5.4 that can do this at [wrklst/docxmustache](https://github.com/wrklst/docxmustache). If you don't use Laravel you can still check this out to understand what is required to manipulate a word doc.

There are also plenty of other classes out there that can handle this:

- [openTBS – Tiny But Strong](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php)
- [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)
- [docxtemplater pro](https://modules.docxtemplater.com) (basic opensource / free version / MIT license available as of writing; image replacing is a commercial plugin)
- [docxpresso](http://www.docxpresso.com) (commercial)
- [phpdocx](https://www.phpdocx.com) (commercial)

Answer (score 0):

To perform populate Microsoft Word Mail Merge or Mustache template in PHP, you may use [Aspose.Words Cloud SDK for PHP](https://products.aspose.cloud/words/php). It is a commercial product but the free plan provides 150 monthly free API calls.

```
<?php

require_once('D:\xampp\htdocs\aspose-words-cloud-php-master\vendor\autoload.php');

//TODO: Get your Client Id and Secret at https://dashboard.aspose.cloud (free registration is required).

$ClientSecret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$ClientId="xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx";

$wordsApi = new Aspose\Words\WordsApi($ClientId,$ClientSecret);

try {
        
$templateName = "SampleMailMergeTemplate.docx";
$outputName = "ExecuteMailMerge_output.docx";
$remoteFolder="Temp";
#read mailmerge data
$data = file_get_contents("SampleMailMergeTemplateData.txt");

##upload template file to storage
$uploadRequest = new Aspose\Words\Model\Requests\UploadFileRequest($templateName,$remoteFolder."/".$templateName,null);
$wordsApi->uploadFile($uploadRequest);

##Execute MailMerge
$request = new Aspose\Words\Model\Requests\ExecuteMailMergeRequest($templateName, $data, $remoteFolder,null, null, null, null,null, null, false, $remoteFolder."/".$outputName);
$result = $wordsApi->executeMailMerge($request);
        
##Download file 
$request = new Aspose\Words\Model\Requests\DownloadFileRequest($remoteFolder."/".$outputName,NULL,NULL);
$result = $wordsApi->downloadFile($request);
copy($result->getPathName(),"MailMerge_output.docx");
print_r($result);
    
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo  "Something went wrong: ",  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

P.S: I'm developer evangelist at Aspose.